# Convert Snippet of JS to JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I want to convert the `javascript` code below to it's equivalent in `JQuery`.

Here's the snippet:

```
<script>
var str = '';
var elem = document.getElementById('formID').elements;
for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
{
    str += "<b>Input Type:</b>" + elem[i].type + "&nbsp&nbsp";
    str += "<b>Input Name:</b>" + elem[i].name + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    str += "<b>current Value:</b><i>" + elem[i].value + "</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    str += "<br>";
} 
  document.getElementById('lblValues').innerHTML = str;
</script>
```

You can see I'm displaying what Inputs are within a Form element. 
But I've reached my understanding of Loops and Elements of an Object. (especially form elements)

```
<script> 
  .........
  // this much I know!
  $("div#lblValues").html(str);
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, jQuery *is* Javascript. What you mean is you want to know how to use the jQuery API to perform the given actions.

Comment: What is `.elements`? I've never seen that nor do I see it listed on MDN.

Comment: @MikeC, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$("#formID input")` selector, this will return an array of inputs inside the form named 'formID'. Then, you can use `each` function to iterate over it. Hope this helps!

```
str = ""
$("#formID input").each(function(elem){
  str += "<b>Input Type:</b>" + elem.type + "&nbsp&nbsp";
  str += "<b>Input Name:</b>" + elem.name + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
  str += "<b>current Value:</b><i>" + elem.value + "</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
  str += "<br>";
})
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Comment: replacing .each(...) with .map(...).join('<br>') could be useful too (and would remove the extra `<br>` at the end)